# implementing search in the header so as to function in all the screens

Tags: android, search, header

I am a newbie to android and apologise if my question is silly. I looked through the net and did not find any proper solution for this.

I want to implement a search function where my edittext is in the header and I want to implement this search function in all the screens with the same functionality. The functionality here is typeahead.

It will be great if I can get some reference to some reading materials which would help me in this or a short hint in any way that can be helpful.

---

Thanks for your help. I tried it but could not get it working as my activity is not launched.  I invested quite a bit of time but did not get through. Is it possible to get a dummy code or prototype with one screen somewhere online so that I can build up on that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the standard Android search interface (which pops up with an edittext in most apps), you'll want to check out [search](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/index.html) on the Android Developers website. It's a really useful article and worth reading through. If you want the functionality in all the activities, do as it says and put the `android.app.default_searchable` meta-data tag in the `<application>` element, not just each `<activity>` one.

Comment: Thanks Espiandev and hooked82. I will go through it and try to figure it out.